# How to consume npm react-art module without bundling?

Tags: npm, reactjs

There is no CDN for [React-art](https://github.com/reactjs/react-art) library. So, I installed it via **npm install react-art** in the local asp.net project.

In the cshtml file where I use the ReactART object, I used the following script:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></Script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.20/require.js"></script>
  <script src="..\..\node_modules\react-art\lib\reactart.js"></script>
```

But I can't get the reference to the **ReactART** object.

How can I consume **react-art** and it's dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `Browserify` or `Webpack` to create js bundle with react-art. They both understand common.js `require` directive. Check out [official example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-art/tree/master/examples/vector-widget) for more info.